# How to compute partial correlation of pixels in R

Tags: raster, r, pixel, correlation, terra

For example, I have 20 years'NDVI and temperature and precipitation rasters.

**At first**,I computed the **pearson correlation coefficent** with those codes as belows.

```
library(terra)
library(Hmisc)
ndvi <- rast(dir("F:/test/NDVI",full.names = T,pattern = '.tif$'))
tem <- rast(dir("F:/test/tem_April",full.names = T,pattern = '.tif$'))
pre <- rast(dir("F:/test/pre_April",full.names = T,pattern = '.tif$'))
z = c(ndvi,tem)
names(z)
nlyr(z)
fun_cor =  function(x) {
  Rs = Hmisc::rcorr(x[1:12], x[13:24], type = "spearman")
  Rx = Rs$r[2]
  Px = Rs$P[2]
  return(c(Rx, Px))
}
r_ndvi_pre = app(z, fun_cor, cores=4)
names(r_ndvi_pre) <- c('coefficient','p_value')
plot(r_ndvi_pre)
```

The results were as expected.
[image]

**Then** I want to compute the **partial correlation coefficent** between NDVI and tem with pre being controled.

I tried to use the similar method, but it didn't work.

And I have used `nlyr` and `names` function to insure if they are right number(dimensions) of layers. The result shows they are 60 layers indeed.And the extent and resolution and CRS(UTM) are all in common.

```
library(terra)
library(ppcor)
ndvi <- rast(dir("F:/test/resosDOY",full.names = T,pattern = '.tif$'))
tem <- rast(dir("F:/test/tem_April",full.names = T,pattern = '.tif$'))
pre <- rast(dir("F:/test/pre_April",full.names = T,pattern = '.tif$'))
z = c(ndvi,tem,pre)
fun_cor =  function(x) {
  Rs = ppcor::pcor.test(x[1:20],x[21:40],x[41:60])
  Rx = Rs$estimate
  Px = Rs$p.value
  return(c(Rx, Px))
}
ndvi_tem_pre = app(z, fun_cor, cores=4)

    -----Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : ===|====
  1610 nodes produced errors; first error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

By the way, my rasters' rows and **columns** are 1510 and **1656** ,**I guess the bug is related to column number and NA values.**

After that，I **searched 2 solutions** that may overcome it.

First, add `if(length(na.omit(x))<60) return(c(NA, NA, NA))`  in `fun_cor`.

```
fun_cor =  function(x) {
  if(length(na.omit(x))<60) return(c(NA, NA, NA))
  Rs = ppcor::pcor.test(x[1:20],x[21:40],x[41:60])
  Rx = Rs$estimate
  Px = Rs$p.value
  return(c(Rx, Px))
}
```

It failed and reported this error:

```
Error in x@ptr$writeValues(v, start - 1, nrows) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double].
In addition: Warning message:
In matrix(r, ncol = nlyr(out), byrow = TRUE) :
  data length [187289] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [93645]
```

Second,use mask function

```
m <- sum(z,na.rm=F)#a+NA=NA
mm <- terra::mask(z,mask=m)
ndvi_tem <- app(mm,fun_cor, cores=8)
```

Unfortunately, it reported the same error as the first.

```
Error in x@ptr$writeValues(v, start - 1, nrows) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double].
In addition: Warning message:
In matrix(r, ncol = nlyr(out), byrow = TRUE) :
  data length [187289] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [93645]
```

Finally，I realized that if I set NA values to -9999, the spatraster will have no NA values!

```
z <- c(ndvi,tem,pre)
z[is.na(z)] <- -9999
```

The result shows I successed.
But,it has a drawback. The pixel time series that contains NA(-9999),computed an inaccurate partial correlation coeffient in my opinion.

Comment: You should write out what your question is instead of linking to an old, dead question on another site. Can you hit the "edit" button and do that? Make a self-contained question, maybe with some sample data and expected output? That would help everyone.

Comment: So sorry about that! I have edited it.

Comment: You're also lacking the package for the `pcor.test` function, so I had to go hunt that down.

Comment: 'pcor.test' is from ‘ppcor’  package. I have library it in the second code.

Comment: "Incorrect number of dimensions" seems to imply that your data isn't the size you think it is. You've not shared your data or any info about it, so we can't do much more. Check that your three objects ndvi, tem, and pre are the shape your expect (20 layers in each?) and edit to show this in your question. I suspect you get an error with `[41:60]` because there's not 60 layers in the object. But that's a guess.

Comment: I checked the layers and others(CRS,res,cell size),they are in common .

Comment: You've used `x[41, 60]` which is trying to select row 41, column 60 from a 2D object, and not `x[41:60]` which selects elements 41 to 60 from a 1-dimensional object. Hence the "incorrect number of dimensions" error. You've carried that over from your original function with its incorrect list indexing, its not in my solution below which should work.

Comment: I can't believe I would make such a mistake! Thank you very much for your patience and professionalism!!! However new problems have arisen, I guess it has something to do with the number of columns, but I don't know why.

Comment: Now your error is related to loaded packages across multiple core processes - see edit in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets first make some test data:

```
sos  = rast(array(runif(10*10*20),c(10,10,20)))
tem  = rast(array(runif(10*10*20),c(10,10,20)))
pre  = rast(array(runif(10*10*20),c(10,10,20)))
NDVI  = rast(array(runif(10*10*20),c(10,10,20)))
z = c(NDVI,tem,pre)
```

and try your function:

```
fun_cor =  function(x) {
  Rs = pcor.test(x[[1:20]],x[[21:40]],x[[41,60]])
  Rx = Rs$estimate
  Px = Rs$p.value
  return(c(Rx, Px))
}
```

and try it:

```
> NDVI_tem_pre = app(z, fun_cor, cores=4)
Error: [app] cannot use this function
Error in x[[1:20]]: attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

This may or may not be the error you get. We don't know - you should **always** show us the error message. I'll assume this.

The problem seems to be that what is passed to the function needs to indexed as a vector, with single square brackets, not as a list with double square brackets. Let's try a slightly modified function:

```
fun_cor =  function(x) {
  Rs = pcor.test(x[1:20],x[21:40],x[41:60])
  Rx = Rs$estimate
  Px = Rs$p.value
  return(c(Rx, Px))
}
NDVI_tem_pre = app(z, fun_cor)
```

No errors and result:

```
> NDVI_tem_pre
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
source      : memory 
names       :        lyr.1,        lyr.2 
min values  : -0.592492106,  0.007515074 
max values  :    0.4532491,    0.9903750
```

Note the documentation for `app` says:

```
 fun: a function that operates on a vector or matrix. This can be a
      function that is defined in base-R or in a package, or a
```

Note if you are doing this with multiple cores, you either need to be explicit to call `ppcor::pcor.test(...)` inside the loop, or use `library(ppcor)` inside the loop if you want to use plain `pcor.test(...)`. The loaded packages are not preserved across multicore sessions.

Comment: I apologize for my wrong way of asking questions. So sorry about that!
I have reedited it ,and posted my processing bugs.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, I re-edited the latest research process, and I am looking forward to your guidance.