# Partial correlation of more than two raster stacks

Tags: r, correlation, rasterstack

Is there a way to compute partial correlation between three raster stacks?

I have 3 rasters namely SIF, SM and VPD.

```
> SIF_stack
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 360, 720, 259200, 10  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.4993056, 0.4986111  (x, y)
extent     : -179.75, 179.75, -89.75, 89.75  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      :   SIF_2007,   SIF_2008,   SIF_2009,   SIF_2010,   SIF_2011,   SIF_2012,   SIF_2013,   SIF_2014,   SIF_2015,   SIF_2016 
min values : -1.1557300, -1.3034987, -0.8319475, -1.0051250, -0.8974480, -0.5803332, -0.9807167, -1.4234057, -1.4280006, -1.6095400 
max values :  1.3002379,  0.9437556,  1.0826364,  1.2223333,  0.8496410,  1.0782150,  0.9539420,  1.1796796,  1.3571700,  2.0684100 

> SM_stack
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 360, 720, 259200, 10  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.4993056, 0.4986111  (x, y)
extent     : -179.75, 179.75, -89.75, 89.75  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      :     SM_2007,     SM_2008,     SM_2009,     SM_2010,     SM_2011,     SM_2012,     SM_2013,     SM_2014,     SM_2015,     SM_2016 
min values : -0.13532482, -0.08336171, -0.15853654, -0.08416149, -0.08670275, -0.09587698, -0.11104368, -0.18544705, -0.10017423, -0.15150067 
max values :  0.18233534,  0.17694922,  0.21045542,  0.22360470,  0.14624325,  0.09941359,  0.08689429,  0.07514318,  0.20897532,  0.07822415 

> VPD_stack
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 360, 720, 259200, 10  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.4993056, 0.4986111  (x, y)
extent     : -179.75, 179.75, -89.75, 89.75  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      :   VPD_2007,   VPD_2008,   VPD_2009,   VPD_2010,   VPD_2011,   VPD_2012,   VPD_2013,   VPD_2014,   VPD_2015,   VPD_2016 
min values : -10.001163,  -8.496811,  -9.105000,  -8.205514,  -6.533477,  -8.031258,  -7.887003, -10.693436,  -5.695960,  -5.756344 
max values :   5.014287,   7.357520,  10.463659,  10.351402,   6.894063,   8.966549,   8.221138,   7.649291,  11.524753,   6.915187
```

I came across the spatialEco package but I would rather keep the raster format.

**EDIT**: I applied this code in ref to this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/430309/how-to-compute-partial-correlation-of-pixels-in-r) but still wondering if there is a "raster" way.

How to compute partial correlation of pixels in R

```
stacked <- c(SIF_stack,
             SM_stack,
             VPD_stack)

fun_cor <- function(x) {
  if (any(!complete.cases(x))) {
    return(c(rep(NA, 2)))
  }
  Rs <- pcor.test(x[1:10], x[11:20], x[21:30], method="pearson")
  Rx <- Rs$estimate
  Px <- Rs$p.value
  return(c(Rx, Px))
}

SIF_sm_vpd <- app(stacked, fun_cor)
```

Comment: The edit you added is done with `{terra}`, which is the continuation of `{raster}` package. Check CRAN: ['terra' is a replacement for the 'raster' package ('terra' can do more, and it is faster and easier to use).](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/terra/index.html)

Comment: You are taking a bit of a shotgun approach here, throwing your data at a perceived solution. You have multiple time measurements across three variables. Time is a stochastic process so, you cannot assume a repeated measure as a uniform distributional process in deriving correlation, this is why we have temporal decomposition and ARIMA models. From a inferential perspective, even a non-parametric implementation of partial/semipartial correlation could fail. At the very least, the data needs to be detrended with numerous papers also incorporating entropy to account for spatial process.

Comment: Hi @JeffreyEvans. Thank you! Why a non-parametric would fail ? Do you have any resources to dive into what you are presenting here? Because I work in a famous research institute... and partial correlation on time series data is very commonly used here. So, I would really appreciate your insights on the matter. Also, the data was detrended (seasonal cycles) to account for part of the stochastic processes.

Comment: Not a good place to go into details but, cross-correlation is a one-to-one statistic so, any lagged relationship would yield a biased or invalid coefficient. This is why warping curves (eg., DTW) are applied for inferring temporal correlations. An applied example would be precipitation and NDVI, where rain fall would create a green-up after the actual event. This lagged effect would not be captured in a cross-correlation. So, again to the point of autoregressive models designed to leverage the autocorrelation function representing lagged effects or a DTW for capturing the temporal correlation.

Comment: Thank you. Very insightful. I haven't heard about the DTW method. Last question:  why Spearman would fail while it does not assume a specific functional form and could therefore detect time lags?